# Make iframe with Vimeo embed, swipable in slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

How do I make iframe swipable with Vimeo embed videos in slick slider? I have found this article, https://fundev.blog/how-to-swipe-youtube-embed-clip-in-slick-gallery-slider-on-mobile/. But I have trouble making it work with Vimeo embed.

I have tried below code, to make it swippable but its not working:

html:

```
echo '<div class="slider-grandparent-contaner">';
echo     '<div class="slider-parent-container">';
echo         '<div class="slider">';
                 foreach ($thirteenth_row['videos'] as $video) {
echo            '<slide>';
echo                '<div class="iframe-container" style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:177.94253938832253%">';
echo                    '<iframe class="sproutvideo-player thirteenth-row-iframe" src="https://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/';
echo                      $video['sprout_id'].'"?playerTheme=dark&amp;playerColor=2f3437 ';
echo                      'style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;border-radius:8px;" frameborder="0"';
echo                      'allowfullscreen referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade">';
echo                    '</iframe>'; 
echo                '</div>';
echo            '</slide>';
               }
echo          '</div>';
echo      '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

jQuery:

```
  $('.slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    prevArrow:
      "<img class='a-left slider-arrow slick-prev' src='/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/home-left-arrow.webp'>",
    nextArrow:
      "<img class='a-right slider-arrow slick-next' src='/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/home-right-arrow.webp'>",
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
        }
      },
    ],
  });
      //Make iframe swippable
  var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName('thirteenth-row-iframe'); // Change this to your iframe's ID

  var startX = 0;
  iframe.contentDocument.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    startX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  });

  iframe.contentDocument.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent vertical scrolling of iframe
    var deltaX = startX - e.touches[0].clientX;
    iframe.contentWindow.scrollBy(deltaX, 0);
    startX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  });
```

Comment: Your HTML has a lot of `echo`. Might want to stay farther back from the microphone... ;) Also, please tell us what the problem is with the implementation rather than making us implement this on our own...